# Coffeescript bind submit form to show div on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

I am trying to display a loading gif when a submit button is pressed, but my coffeescript doesn't seem to be working. How can I use Coffeescript to show a div when I submit a form?

Coffeescript:

```
$(document).ready ->
$('form#add_product_form').submit ->
    console.log("test")
    $("#circularG").show()
    false
```

HTML form:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/products/new" data-remote="true" id="add_product_form" method="post"><div style="display:none"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"></div>
      <p>
        <label for="link_url">Url</label><br>
        <input autofocus="autofocus" id="link_url" name="link[url]" type="text">
      </p>

      <p>

        <input class="btn btn-primary" name="commit" type="submit" value="Add Product">
      </p>
</form>
```

My Coffeescript is being compiled into js as so:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
return $('form#add_product_form').submit(function() {
  console.log("test");
  $("#circularG").show();
  return false;
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add space before the 2nd line

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('form#add_product_form').submit -> #HERE
    console.log("test")
    $("#circularG").show()
    false
```

Comment: I tried this, did not work though =/ any reason why this space would make a difference? Coffeescript syntax?

Comment: Yes, with this space, the code will work when the document is ready. The whole code is a callback for the ready function.

Comment: Are you sure Jquery is loaded, and #circularG exists ?

Comment: Yes, Jquery is loaded, and I have a div with id=circularG. Even if I didn't, "test" should print to console, which does not happen

Comment: OOOH I Got the answer ! it should be ('form#add_product_form').submit not ...#add_product_button. The submit is called on the form not on the button :) .. See your compiled JS

Comment: Oh I must've posted the code in between my edits, both my form and js are tagged with 'add_product_form', and I am still having issues =[ - edited my question appropriately

Comment: put the code of the whole page somewhere. I tested this code in the browser and it's working. So the problem might be somewhere else !

Comment: Yes, I found the problem, I believe. The current form is being rendered in Rails after clicking a button, and the controller is rendering js and inserting the form into the template. It seems like because of this, the js isn't noticing the new html form that appears on the page. If I include the compiled javascript in the html file that is being rendered after pressing the button (that includes the form), it works fine. Thanks for helping weed out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to attach "submit" event to a FORM element e.g.

```
  $('#id_for_form').submit ->
    $('.div').show()
```